# Finding matching and nonmatching items in lists

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python and am getting a little confused as to what you can and can't do with lists. I have two lists that I want to compare and return matching and nonmatching elements in a binary format. `List1` is of constant length, while the length of `List2` differs (but is always shorter than `List1`).

For example:

```
List1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'pig', 'donkey']
List2 = ['dog', 'cat', 'donkey']
```

Output wanted:

```
List3 = [1, 1, 0, 1]
```

The code I have so far is:

```
def match_nonmatch(List1, List2):
    List3 = []
    for i in range(len(List1)):
        for j in range(len(List2)):
            if List1[i] == List2[j]:
                List3.append(1)
            else:
                List3.append(0)
   return List3
```

I am able to return the matches when I compare the lists, but when I include the else statement shown above to return the nonmatches I end up with a list that is way longer than it should be. For instance, when I use a list comparing 60 items, I get a list that contains 3600 items rather than 60.

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain to me the problem with my code as it currently stands and suggest how I could modify the code so it does what I want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use the following code.

```
listt3=[]

for i in listt1:
    if i in listt2:
        listt3.append(1)
    else:
        listt3.append(0)
```

If you prefer one-liners,

`listt3=[ 1 if i in listt2 else 0 for i in listt1]`

Comment: @Srinivas and Platypus : Don't you think this would not give the exact output that is required?
the listt1 and listt2 should be swapped for the exact output.

Comment: @Srinivas Anytime... This code could be better converted into a one-liner `listt3=[int(i in listt2) for i in listt1]`

Comment: yep,agreed,but OP is newbie to python. :)

Comment: @SandipAgarwal much better would be `listt3=[ 1 if i in listt2 else 0 for i in listt1]`....happy now ? :)

Comment: @Srinivas Hey, thats really much better. It didn't hit me even. Thanx. :D

Answer (score 22):

Use `set` instead of `list`. This way you can do lots of nice things:

```
set1 = set(['dog', 'cat', 'pig', 'donkey'])
set2 = set(['dog', 'cat', 'donkey'])

matched = set1.intersection(set2) # set(['dog', 'cat', 'donkey'])
unmatched = set1.symmetric_difference(set2) # set(['pig'])
```

I know it's not exactly what you asked for, but it's usually a better practice to use sets instead of lists when doing this sort of things.

More on sets here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: Thanks for the link for sets. Haven't come across the concept before so will read up.

Answer (score 5):

You can use bitwise operation too:

```
List1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'pig', 'donkey']  
List2 = ['dog', 'cat', 'donkey']
```

matching:

```
set(List1) & set(List2)
```

not matching:

```
set(List1) ^ set(List2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would do it if `list2` is short:

```
list1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'pig', 'donkey']
list2 = ['dog', 'cat', 'donkey']
list3 = [int(val in list2) for val in list1]
print(list3)
```

This prints:

```
[1, 1, 0, 1]
```

If `list2` is long, you could convert it to a `set` first to make the code more efficient:

```
list1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'pig', 'donkey']
set2 = set(['dog', 'cat', 'donkey'])
list3 = [int(val in set2) for val in list1]
print(list3)
```

The reason your current code produces too many elements is that you call `append()` on every iteration of the inner loop, and there are `len(List1) * len(List2)` such iterations.

Here is how it can be fixed:

```
def match_nonmatch(List1, List2):
    List3 = []
    for i in range(len(List1)):
        for j in range(len(List2)):
            if List1[i] == List2[j]:
                List3.append(1)
                break             # fix #1
        else:                     # fix #2
            List3.append(0)
    return List3
```

Note the added `break` and the fact that the `else` clause is now refers to the inner `for` and not the `if`.

That said, I'd still use the one-liner at the top of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After reading this and other replies, I will look into sets - haven't come across the concept before.

Comment: @aix Don't you think there would be an error raised at the line of the `else` statement?

Comment: @SandipAgarwal: No, I don't. I've tested the code before posting and it works. `for`...`else` is valid construct in Python -- look it up.

Comment: @aix Hey, it works. Some problem on my side. Don't you think writing the one-liner is better?

Comment: @SandipAgarwal: I do. See the last sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'pig', 'donkey']; list2 = ['dog', 'cat', 'donkey']
>>> [i in list2 for i in list1]
[True, True, False, True]
```

Also, you should read PEP8, CamelCase names are commonly used for classes only.

Answer (score 0):

```
[int(i==j) for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.